# MySqlBulkLoader with Column Mapping?

Tags: c#, mysql, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I use `SqlBulkCopy` to do bulk inserts into a SQL Server database. I am now providing *MySql* support for my program and the nearest thing to `SqlBulkCopy` is `MySqlBulkLoader`. But in `MySqlBulkLoader`, I have to first convert my `DataTable` to a file because `MySqlBulkLoader` only works with files and not `DataTable`. And then I have to disable foreign key checks before the insert. I have done them both but now I am left with one more problem:

My destination table has an identity column (auto-increment and PK) and `MySqlBulkLoader` maps the first column in the source file to this column and therefore only the first record is inserted with wrong column mappings. Here is how I use the function if it helps:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn);
    bl.TableName = tableName;
    bl.Timeout = 600;
    bl.FieldTerminator = ",";
    bl.LineTerminator = "\r\n";
    bl.FileName = tempFilePath;
    bl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
    numberOfInsertedRows = bl.Load();
}
```

And this is first few lines on my file:

```
CampaignRunId,RecipientId,IsControlGroup
27,"testrecipient_0",False
27,"testrecipient_1",False
27,"testrecipient_2",False
27,"testrecipient_3",False
27,"testrecipient_4",False
27,"testrecipient_5",False
27,"testrecipient_6",False
27,"testrecipient_7",False
27,"testrecipient_8",False
27,"testrecipient_9",False
27,"testrecipient_10",False
27,"testrecipient_11",False
27,"testrecipient_12",False
27,"testrecipient_13",False
```

Is there a way to provide column mapping for `MySqlBulkLoader`? I see that it has a `Columns` property but it is read-only.

There is a library written somewhere called [MySqlBulkCopy](http://code.google.com/p/mysqlbulkcopy/) but I ran into other problems using it and it does not come from an official source.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently been using MySqlBulkLoader also, and came across the need to use the Columns property in order to format a date that was pulled out of MSSQL into the right format to insert into MySQL. The columns property is readonly, but that just means you need to set the properties when you create the object, rather than afterwards.

First, change this block of code

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn);
    bl.TableName = tableName;
    bl.Timeout = 600;
    bl.FieldTerminator = ",";
    bl.LineTerminator = "\r\n";
    bl.FileName = tempFilePath;
    bl.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1;
    numberOfInsertedRows = bl.Load();
}
```

to this:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn)
    {
        TableName = tableName,
        Timeout = 600,
        FieldTerminator = ",",
        LineTerminator = "\r\n",
        FileName = tempFilePath,
        NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1
    };
    var numberOfInsertedRows = bl.Load();
}
```

Then, you can go ahead an use whatever value you want to for the Columns property, so your final code block may look something like this:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn)
    {
        TableName = tableName,
        Timeout = 600,
        FieldTerminator = ",",
        LineTerminator = "\r\n",
        FileName = tempFilePath,
        NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1,
        Columns = { "CampaignRunId", "RecipientId", "IsControlGroup" }
    };
    var numberOfInsertedRows = bl.Load();
}
```

Comment: Your code works only if the columns are explicitly listed. As soon as I try to use a variable (a list of strings or a string array) instead, it doesn't compile because it says that the `Columns` property is read-only. I don't know at priori the columns, so I cannot use your suggestion. Is there another solution?

Comment: @winterlude, David's answer uses the object initialiser syntax to add elements into the List. You can omit the Columns property from the inititialiser block and instead call `bl.Columns.AddRange(columns)`

Answer (score 0):

Building on David Hartley's answer: if you don't know the column names a priori, you could just clear the list of column and add items to it afresh.

It'll be something like this:

`bl.Columns.Clear();
 foreach (string col in yourColumns)
 {
    bl.Columns.Add(col);
 }`