# Insert ExcelSheet data into MySql Database using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

In the solution with MS SQL the code looks like below.
 Now I try to do something similar for MySQL.I tried using MysqlBulkLoader but it is not working

```
SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connect);
    //MySqlBulkLoader objbulk = new MySqlBulkLoader(connect);

    //assigning Destination table name
    objbulk.DestinationTableName = "barter_proposals";
    //Mapping Table column
    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("company", "company");
    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("website_a", "website_a");
    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("email_id", "email_id");
    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("contact_name", "contact_name");
    //inserting Datatable Records to DataBase
    connect.Open();
    objbulk.WriteToServer(Exceldt);
    connect.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MySqlBulkLoader` uses pretty different way from `SqlBulkCopy` to perform bulk insert/update: it utilizes file-based input (e.g. TXT or CSV) instead directly using `DataTable` instance. As a workaround, you can export `DataTable` to a CSV file and read the contents by `MySqlBulkLoader` like examples below:

**1) DataTable to CSV Conversion**

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter("/path/to/source/file.csv", false))
{
    // assume Exceldt is your 'DataTable' object
    int colCount = Exceldt.Columns.Count;
    foreach (DataRow row in Exceldt.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
        {
            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(row[i]))
            {
                sw.Write(row[i].ToString());
            }
            if (i < colCount - 1)
            {
                sw.Write(",");
            }
        }
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
    }
}
```

**2) `MySqlBulkLoader` Bulk Insert from CSV File**

```
// creating bulk loader instance
MySqlBulkLoader objbulk = new MySqlBulkLoader(connect);
objbulk.TableName = "barter_proposals";
objbulk.Timeout = 600; // set command timeout
objbulk.FieldTerminator = ",";
objbulk.LineTerminator = "\r\n";
objbulk.FileName = "/path/to/source/file.csv";
objbulk.NumberOfLinesToSkip = 1; // adjust this depending on CSV file headers

objbulk.Load();

// delete the CSV file here (optional)
```

References:

[Using the MySqlBulkLoader Class (5.13) - MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html)

[MySQL - Bulk data import using .NET Connector MySqlBulkLoader Class](https://theonetechnologies.com/blog/post/mysql-bulk-data-import-using-net-connector-mysqlbulkloader-class)

[MySqlBulkLoader with Column Mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691620/mysqlbulkloader-with-column-mapping)